# Twitter App showing code: 89 Invalid or expired token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have an app that uses the Twitter API where users can authenticate via twitter and retweet/like/follow through my app.  Randomly this week the logs are showing "code: 89 Invalid or expired token".

Naturally, I go login to twitter to see the status of my app, and nothing seems out of the ordinary.  I saw others with this issue had success regenerating their keys and replacing them in their application.

This didn't help.

One important thing to note is nothing has changed in the code of my application for the last 3-4 months, so I doubt it's anything in there.  It's been working for over two years without any issue.

The thing I suspect the most is perhaps Twitter decided to suspend my app; Although, I don't see anywhere that is the case, and I thought I'd receive an email from them about it if it were.

I'm at a loss and would appreciate some possible solutions or alternative avenues I can pursue to find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys associated with your app are the API Key (Consumer Token) and API secret key (Consumer Secret). The error you're getting is for the Access token, which belongs to the user. It sounds like the user associated with that request needs to authorize your app again before it can operate again with their access key. This can happen if the user removes authorization for your app by visiting their Settings/Privacy and safety/Apps and sessions.

If you were using your own access token in a scenario like single-user authorization, then regenerating the key might work, but in this case, the only way to get new keys for that user is for them to go through the sign-in process to authorize your app again. e.g. you could log who the user was that the error occurred on and send them a notification to re-authorize.

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation! Regenerating the key and reauthorizing fixed the issue.